# R: changing entries of a dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I have to summarize the information of an AnnotatedDataFrame and a graphNEL together. My problem is that the same "feature" in the data frame and in the graphNEL has different names: in the data frame I have *NAME* and *IDnumber* separately (two columns), in the graphNEL I have a single column whose entries are in the form *NAME(IDnumber)*. It is a very large dataset, so it is absolutely out of question to rename them manually. Is there a way to make the dataset entries in the form *NAME(IDnumber)*?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's always wise to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (also, you might want to read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your dataframe is called `df`, you can create a new variable with:

```
df$new <- paste0(df$NAME, "(", df$IDnumber, ")")
```